# CozyRoc SSIS, reading email attachment filename?

Tags: ssis

In a package where I harvest all mail attachments (example found here:[cozyroc documentation](http://www.cozyroc.com/ssis/receive-mail-task)), I would like to read the attachment filename and according to that, store attachments in different folders.

Anyone knows if and how can I do this using Cozyroc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like there's an easy way to extract the attachment file names from the CozyRoc email object. What I would do is save all attachments to a single "staging" folder, then create a For Each Loop to loop through all the files in that staging folder, and then use File System tasks to move the files.

Comment: thank you, i did it the way you proposed. I have added some mailserver tasks before i download to the staging folder i.e move emails to sub-inbox folders etc. Do you know any way to check if an email has an attachment before i download it?  What i wanna do is download only emails with attachments..